# add-qadpermission to grant right readproperty to all users for nt authority\Authenticated users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to grant ReadProperty on all user objects from AD to the group "NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users".

I found `add-qadpermission` cmdlet from quest/dell activeroles snap in but I don't know how it works.

I tried this syntax but it doesn't work:

```
add-QADpermission  mydom\orwell   -Account "NT AUTHORITY\Utilisateurs Authentifiés" -Right ReadProperty
```

It returns:

```
Can't lookup account for identity: 'NT AUTHORITY\utilisateurs authentifiés'

No valid accounts specified. Searching permissions for all accounts.
```

And when I try with `NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated users` it say me the same message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to at least use `NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users` and not the .. french? .. name, since `Authenticated Users` is a special built-in group. If that doesn't work, you could try using it's SID:

```
S-1-5-11
```

Like:

```
Add-QADPermission -Identity 'mydom\orwell' -Account "S-1-5-11" -Rights ReadProperty
```

Unless you need to give machine accounts access or users from a trusted domain, you could use `Domain Users` as an alternative if the above doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for you answer.
finaly found how to do by using Dell - quest tools activeroles management shell.
Here is command that worked for me:
'Get-QADUser  * | foreach-object { Add-QADPermission $_.dn -Account "utilisateurs authentifiés"  -Rights 'ReadControl,ReadProperty'}

Answer (score 0):

thank you for you answer. finaly found how to do by using Dell - quest tools activeroles management shell.

Here is command that worked for me:

```
Get-QADUser * | foreach-object { 
  Add-QADPermission $_.dn -Account "utilisateurs authentifiés" -Rights 'ReadControl,ReadProperty'
}
```